# Almost-Kahler Einstein four manifolds

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry, kahler-manifolds

Are the odd-degree Betti numbers of a compact Almost-Kahler Einstein four manifold necessarily even ?

Comment: If some of Betti numbers were odd this would obviously contradict to 
Goldberg's conjecture, stating that Almost-Kahler Einstein manifolds are Kahler. I assume Goldberg's conjecture is open in all dimensions?

Comment: Sorry for the double-retag.  I think these tags should work.

Comment: this is W. Watson's conjecture, which it seems is still open: http://facpub.stjohns.edu/~watsonw/diffgeom.htm (edited "odd" --> "odd-degree" to avoid a contradictio in terminis)